# Error with ffmpeg in android (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError)

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I am facing this java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in android. While i have also androidndk and other essential parts required for running ffmpeg in android like jni folder files ffmped, armeabi, build_ files etc. I have figured it out a lot of time but its not fixed yet. Please guide me about my problem.
This is my basic code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static {
    System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");
   System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg-test-jni");
}
TextView text_titlebar_text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      text_titlebar_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);

        showVideoInfo(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()+ "/video.mp4"));
}

//declare the jni functions
private static native void naInit(String _videoFileName);
private static native int[] naGetVideoResolution();
private static native String naGetVideoCodecName();
private static native String naGetVideoFormatName();
private static native void naClose();

private void showVideoInfo(final File _file) {
   String videoFilename = _file.getAbsolutePath();
   naInit(videoFilename);
   int[] prVideoRes = naGetVideoResolution();
    String prVideoCodecName = naGetVideoCodecName();
    String prVideoFormatName = naGetVideoFormatName();
    naClose();
    String displayText = "Video: " + videoFilename + "\n";
    displayText += "Video Resolution: " + prVideoRes[0] + "x" + prVideoRes[1] + "\n";
    displayText += "Video Codec: " + prVideoCodecName + "\n";
    displayText += "Video Format: " + prVideoFormatName + "\n";
    text_titlebar_text.setText(displayText);


}
```

}

and this is a LogCat

```
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load ffmpeg from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.testone-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testone-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:514)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at com.example.testone.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:16)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-01 07:04:18.862: E/AndroidRuntime(4653):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 07:04:18.921: E/AppErrorDialog(496): Failed to get ILowStorageHandle instance
```

Comment: Did you build ffmpeg?  Is it in the correct spot for your IDE (either Eclipse or Android Studio) to know to put it into the APK?  Because its not being packaged as part of your APK, thus loading it is failing.

Comment: I haven't build ffmpeg but everything is setup and at correct place.

Comment: I just copy all files from an existing android project and change them according to my project environment

Comment: Are you using a prebuilt version of the .so?  If not, and if you haven't built it, then that's your problem.  If using a prebuilt, is it built for the correct processor architecture?

Comment: Ithink now you are right, so how to get the correct processor architecture??

Comment: I have AMD athlone x2

Comment: Most phones are ARM.  AN emulator may be ARM or x86.  Make sure you have the proper version of the .so file for where you're running it.  AMD vs Intel doesn't matter.